# What is the purpose of meta tag MSSmartTagsPreventParsing?

Tags: asp.net, html, internet-explorer, xhtml, seo

What does it do? is there any benefit to adding this in the `<head>` for all browsers?

```
<meta name="MSSmartTagsPreventParsing" content="true">
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It disables a feature that only appeared in the IE6 betas.

Comment: Do you care about users of IE6 beta (given that it was time limited and no longer works)?

Comment: @Jitendra, nope, I think it's no longer supported even by MS itself.

Comment: after post a question i just found on this site http://www.optimet.net/meta_tag_explanation.htm "To stop this traffic thievery, just insert the prevent Smart Tags meta tag in each page."

Comment: @Jitendra - Ignore that site. It sounds like it hasn't been updated in almost a decade. The advice is garbage. You don't need to worry about disabling a feature that has never appeared in a non-beta browser.

Comment: FYI, if you were interested in what the Smart Tags feature was and why they removed it from final IE6, articles on it are not hard to find.

Answer (score 13):

Wikipedia have a good write-up on Microsoft's "Smart Tags" feature:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_tag_%28Microsoft%29

As soon as the feature was announced, many web developers reacted with hostility at the thought of having their content hijacked by third parties. A lot of sites pre-emptively added the above header to their pages to disable the feature, even though it never actually was publicly released (beta only). And of course, the headers stuck around :)