# Is MSSmartTagsPreventParsing still valid meta tag?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, web

Is the Meta Tag - MSSmartTagsPreventParsing - still a valid and used tag in current browsers?

Any harm in leaving it on a website?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of <meta name="MSSmartTagsPreventParsing" content="TRUE">?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167301/what-is-the-purpose-of-meta-name-mssmarttagspreventparsing-content-true)

Answer (score 1):

It won't hurt to keep it. I still always use it "just in case" MS wants to insert ad links over my web page content.